# How do I determine one year prior to a given date 2017-08-23 with python datetime?

Tags: python, date, datetime

I am trying to identify a date one year prior to 2017-08-23.

All of the examples I have seen where one year prior to a given date shows the use of `datetime.datetime.now()`.  I need to determine one year prior to 2017-08-23.

```
last_date = 2017-08-23
one_year_prior = last_date - dt.timedelta(days=3*365)
```

> unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'datetime.timedelta'

I was hoping to get one year prior to 2017-08-23.  I need the date formatted yyyy-mm-dd for the next part of the homework.

Comment: Look into how to create a DateTime object where you provide the Date String (which is what you are storing in last_date) instead of calling datetime.datetime.now() method.  BTW your posted code would perform a 3-year time reversion, not one (3 * 365)

Comment: you can make a datetime that's subtractable like this: datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 23, 0, 0)

Answer (score 0):

In order to apply `timedelta()`, you need to *convert your string to a datetime*. One way to do it would be to use `strptime()`:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta

>>> s = "2017-08-23"

>>> dt = datetime.strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%d")

>>> one_year_prior = dt - timedelta(days=365)
>>> one_year_prior
datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 23, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a date with dateutil.parser

```
import dateutil.parser
yourdate = dateutil.parser.parse("2017-08-23")
```

Then use that instead

Be warned when using timedelta leap years might bring inconveniences:

```
date(2012, 1, 1) + timedelta(days=365) → date(2012, 12, 31)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your object `last_date` needs to be a `datetime` object. You can can make it into a datetime object using `last_date = datetime.date(<year>, <month>, <day>)` then your formula should work just fine. You can cast the resulting object as `str` to get the answer back with the same formatting.

Answer (score 0):

This is one year before and this should format it for you as well

```
y = datetime.datetime(2017,8,23) - datetime.timedelta(days=1*365)                                                                                       

In [457]: y                                                                                                                                                   
datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 23, 0, 0)

print(str(y.year) + '-' + str(y.month) + '-' + str(y.day))
2016-8-23
```

Comment: `y.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` is way easier